# Comparing 2-Dimensional and 1-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have searched the site but struggling to find how to achieve what I am hoping to.  I am dynamically creating the below array, then sorting it. Now that I have done that I want to compare the second level keys [35659] etc.. to values in another array.

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [35659] => 1
            [35735] => 2
        )
    [199] => Array
        (
            [35659] => 1
            [35699] => 1
        )
    [118] => Array
        (
            [35659] => 1
        )
)
```

This is other array that holds product id's

```
Array
(
    [0] => 35659
    [1] => 35699
    [2] => 35735
)
```

So what I am trying to achieve is while the 2nd array values exist in the first array print them out once each productid has been met once I want to break.

So my desired outcome would be the below, as all three values from the product id's array have been met.

```
   [11] => Array
        (
            [35659] => 1
            [35735] => 2
        )

  [199] => Array
        (
            [35699] => 1
        )
```

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the 1st array and add an element if it's in the 2nd array while keeping count how many elements you've added. If you've added all elements, break the iteration.

```
$results = array();
$count = 0;

foreach($array as $key => $subarray) {
    foreach($subarray as $subkey => $subvalue) {
        if(in_array($subkey,$second_array)) {
            $results[$key][$subkey] = $subvalue;
            if(++$count == count($second_array))
                break 2;
        }
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/NDh1wtZu)

Comment: awesome, thank you. What does the 2 do in the "break 2"?

Comment: @user2433317 without the 2, it would just break the inner foreach and move to the next iteration of the outer foreach. the 2 breaks the outer foreach